# Can I use Late Static Binding for non-static members?

Tags: php, late-static-binding

[The documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#language.oop5.late-static-bindings) says that:

> This feature was named "late static bindings" with an internal
> perspective in mind. "Late binding" comes from the fact that static::
> will not be resolved using the class where the method is defined but
> it will rather be computed using runtime information. It was also
> called a "static binding" as **it can be used for (but is not limited
> to) static method calls**.

What does it  mean by "*not limited* to static methods only"?

I'm just trying to understand that, **I don't want to do something concrete**, an example would be nice, for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The place I most commonly use it is when you want to override a constant in an inheriting class, but it's used in a method that's not also overridden in the inheriting class:

```php
class A
{
    const FOO = 'A';
    public function foo()
    {
        printf("I am: %s\n", get_class($this));
        printf("self::FOO = %s\n", self::FOO);
        printf("static::FOO = %s\n", static::FOO);
        echo "\n";
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    const FOO = 'B';
}
```

Here, if we run the inherited method that uses `self::`, we'll get the value that's defined in the parent class, not the instantiated class. I.e., inside the `B` class, `self::FOO` has a value of `A` if it's referred to by a method inherited from `A`. So `self::` will give us the class where the method is defined, and `static::` will give us the class we happen to be in at runtime.

```php
(new A())->foo();
(new B())->foo();
```

Outputs:

```
I am: A
self::FOO = A
static::FOO = A

I am: B
self::FOO = A
static::FOO = B
```

So this is not a static method call, but we're still using the `static::` keyword to make sure we get the overriding value, if any.

Comment: HI @Alex Howansky, sorry for the late reply, I just got into SO. Excellent example, so, the documentation references that we can use `static::` **inside** non-static methods, right?

Comment: I'm not sure if the documentation references it, but you definitely can.

Comment: Ok, anyway your example is a good one @Alex Howansky